# ServletFileUpload encoding issue

Tags: java, encoding

I am using Apache commons fileupload API for uploading a file from UI. In the file there is a entry as given below:

```
<name>m²</name>
```

But after loading the file, the character turning into below character

```
<name>mÂ²</name>
```

I am not sure if there is something with encoding to do here. Guide please

Answer (score 0):

It appears the uploaded file is XML. In first place the file should be plain text and use entity encoding for superscript 2. Ideally `<name>m²</name>` should be **<name>m&#178;</name>**, where is &#178; is the superscript 2 character. The xml processors are supposed to translate this entity character accordingly.
The reference to [Wikipedia with ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) charset that shows character chart under **Codepage layout** section.