# XML file upload in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Could someone please help me with some guide for uploading XML file in Servlet.

Is there anything available with ServletFileUpload from Apache.

Comment: ServletFileUpload handles files, regardless of their form. What have you tried this far? Maybe you could show us some code and point out what exactly is your problem? Showing some effort in terms of code, non-working more often than working of course, would most likely attract more, and better, answers to your question (see also [some guidelines about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: Thanks Sami for the comment. Could you please look into my previous question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746295/servletfileupload-encoding-issue/34747374#34747374